# extract portion of text from cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-arguments

I need to extract a portion of text from a text file log.txt, where the contents of the file are as follows.

```
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE 
services                                    0  Disc                        
console                                     1  Conn                        
                   input1                   3  Disc                        
 rdp-tcp#0         input2                   4  Active  rdpwd               
                   input3                   6  Disc                        
 rdp-tcp                                 65536  Listen
```

Specifically, I need the SESSION ID of a specific username. 
Need help in extracting the same. 
Any advice or help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to extract all the usernames and IDs?

Comment: and can you humor us with what the command was that generated this response?

Comment: No, just one user session, say for input1 I need the SESSION ID. 
And, I used qwinsta to get that response.

Comment: So you want to be able to specify a username and get their session?

Comment: If you know a specific username you want to get the ID for, you can filter the output by invoking `qwinsta` with the username as a parameter.

Comment: @uSlackr FYI [`query session` command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754415.aspx). Need to be run on the server which is running terminal services (supposedly _not_ on Windows 7/8 _home_). However this does not matter as the OP needs to extract some data _from a text file_ `log.txt`. Looping `for /F` against  either a text file content or a command output would be the same though...

Comment: @BenN Yes, I can do that and get only a single line as output, but still I would need to extract the ID from that line.



Thanks

Comment: @JosefZ Yes, looking for a `for` command to extract the ID from the CL line or the text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next script shows possible approach using [extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html).

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%G in ("D:\test\QuerySessionLog.txt") do (
  set "logline=%%~G"
  set "_SESSIONNAME=!logline:~0,18!"
  set "_USERNAME=!logline:~18,18!"
  set "_ID=!logline:~36,11!"
  set "_STATE=!logline:~47,8!"
  set "_TYPE=!logline:~55,7!"
  set "_DEVICE=!logline:~62!"

  echo !logline!
  for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%g in ('set _') do (
    set "trimentry=%%h"
    if "!trimentry:~0,1!"==">" (
      call :TRIM !trimentry:~1!
    ) else (
      call :TRIM !trimentry!
    )
    echo %%g=[!trimresult!] ^(raw=[%%h]^) 
  )
  echo( 
) 
:endlocal
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:TRIM
  SET "trimresult=%*"
GOTO :EOF
```

Please note that I'm absolutely not sure about rightness of column widths as another example provided in [`query session` command reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754415.aspx) shows another format. 
However, column widths could be computable from the header line (but this would exceed current question topic).

Comment: Thanks a lot Josef, that was exactly what I wanted.
Thanks to everyone else who tried.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like fixed-width data, so let's use GNU awk: user "input2" has id "4"

```
$ gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS="19 25 3 99" -v user=input2 '$2 ~ "^"user {print $3}' log.txt
4
```

Comment: Oops, didn't notice this was for windows. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, Yes I need it for windows.